# ag-Grid Cell data value?

Tags: ag-grid

Using Ag-Grid and trying to set event when user clicks on cell I want to get its data value.

My console is printing this: >{rowIndex:4, rowPinned: null, column: t}

I have a value of 10.50 in there, trying to retrieve it.

Not working at all please advise...

```
var gridOptions = {
      columnDefs: columnDefs,
      rowData: rowData,
      onCellClicked: function(event) { 
          
          
        var focusedCell=gridOptions.api.getFocusedCell()
        
        
        console.log(focusedCell)  
          
          
          },
      
      suppressMovableColumns:true,
      
    };
```

Comment: console(event) first, it probably contains the row data or some kind of id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do `event.value` to retrieve the value of clicked cell

```
const cellValue = event.value;
```